# powershell email log file in the body of the email

Tags: powershell

I am using this power-shell script to send emails. My problem is with the $body variable. I don't want to attach the log file in the email, I want the contents of the log file to be in the body of the email.

```
Write-Host "Setting Variables" -ForegroundColor Green
    $user    = "username"
    $pass    = Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot\pass.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
    $cred    = New-Object -Typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $user,$pass
    $from    = "sender@domain.net"
    $to      = "recipient@domain.net"
    $subject = "Email Subject"
    $body    = Get-Content C:\backup\log.txt
    $smtp    = "smtp.gmail.com"

    Write-Host "Sending Email" -ForegroundColor Green
    Send-MailMessage -From $from -To $to -Subject $subject -Body $body -SmtpServer $smtp -Port 587 -UseSsl -Credential $cred
```

When I run the script I get a message saying:

```
Send-MailMessage : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 
'System.String' required by parameter 'Body'. Specified method is not 
supported.
```

How can I read the contents of the log file and put it in the body of the email?

Comment: What do you get in powershell when issuing `Get-Content C:\backup\log.txt`? Maybe an encoding problem? Did you try casting to `[string]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this solved it

```
-Body ($body | Out-String)
```